# Postgresql: получить слова из словаря

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql

У меня в postgresql есть словарь russian_hunspell. Это морфологический словарь. Я хочу sql командой получить всю морфологию по одному слову, или список лексем форм слова. Например, ввести слово "книга", и чтобы мне в результате вывелось "книги", "книгу", "книге". Какую команду sql можно использовать для этого?Или как это можно организовать?

Comment: Не думаю, что такая возможность есть, так как эти словари в *PostgreSQL* используются для обратной задачи: получения корня из разных форм.  У самого `hunspell` есть утилита `wordforms`, но её часто надо собирать отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *column_name* FROM *table_name* WHERE *column_name* LIKE '%name%';

Здесь знак % означает любые символы.